# .NET c#: Why does Visual studio expect me to put my files in c:\...\myConsoleApplication\bin\Debug

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015

I'm new to .NET programming and I get the following exception when trying to load an xml file that's located in my project's root. 
Can someone please explain to me why the program is looking for my file in the bin folder?
Here's the exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: Le file'c:\users\u957974\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\XMLINQConsoleApplication\XMLINQConsoleApplication\bin\Debug\contacts.xml' est not found.

[image: Here is a screenshot of my project]

Comment: File properties, Check the box for "copy to output directory".

Comment: It simply because,  the compiled code (dll,exe..etc) stored in your application bin folder. In your code, you are trying to load the xml file from your application build path (While running). which mean your compiled application expect the xml file from its own directory.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio doesn't know that your application needs that file to run. You have to tell it.

To do this, right-click the file in Solution Explorer. Choose "Properties".

Under Properties, find "Copy to Output Directory", and select "Copy if newer".

Answer (score 0):

Because that is where the output of your program will compile. The resulted `.exe` file (assuming this is a console app) will be generated in `bin/Debug/`.

If you want to load the file from the root of your project, use a relative path like `XElement.Load("../../contacts.xml")`

Comment: "contacts.xml" is relative path too

Comment: yes, it is relative to `bin/Debug`, so it will find the file in the root folder

Comment: No, it is relative to the current directory and that is here hopefully the application output path. That is just a "crossing finger" solution. Nothing you can rely on

Comment: Yes, you are right. I assumed that the `.exe` is in the `bin/Debug` and will be run from there

Answer (score 0):

A *relative* file path is resolved from the current directory. The current directory when running the application from Visual Studio is the application directory.

But be aware that current directory can change at any time by several operations like OpenFileDialog

Answer (score 0):

Bin folder is the working directory of any .Net project which you create.The Bin folder contains all the compiled assemblies. It has all the referenced Dlls and resources which the project is using. Since you have not specified the path for your Xml file it is trying to find it in the current directory and hence the exception.

You can try specifying the path like :

```
Xelement Xmldoc =  XElement.Load("../../contacts.xml")
```

Answer (score -1):

Give path like this

```
   Xelement Xmldoc = Xelement.Load("~/COntracts.xml");
```

Comment: The question refers to a console application, not a web application.